# Why is there no speedup with multithreading for updating the array

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading

Here, we write a code for testing the speedup of multi-threading update a array for 10,000,000 times. On some machines with 2*intel E5-2620v2 CPU, centos 6.5, g++ 4.7.2, we find that 2-tread is much slower than single thread one.
While on a machine with 2*intel E5-2660v2 CPU, centos 6.5, g++ 4.7.2, and windows machine, we observed the speedup. And if we replace the code  with note 1 with "a[j]=i+j;", we obtain speedup too.
The memory bandwidth of the two class linux machine are same.

```
double a[1000];
void test(long long int number){
    for(int i =0;i<number;i++){
        for(int j = 0;j<1000;j++){
           a[j] +=i;               //*1*

        }
    }
}
int main(){

    int th = 1;
    thread worker[th];
    long long int number[th];

    for(int i=0; i<th; i++){
        number[i] = 10000000/th;
    }

    struct timeval start, end;
    gettimeofday( &start, NULL );

    for(int i=0; i<th; i++){
        worker[i] = thread(test,number[i]);
    }

    for(int i=0; i<th; i++){
       worker[i].join();
    }
    gettimeofday( &end, NULL );

    double iterate_time =(end.tv_sec-start.tv_sec)+(end.tv_usec-start.tv_usec)/1000000.0;
    cout << iterate_time<<endl;
}
```

Comment: The task you're multithreading is petty. You need a more time consuming task to test with.

Comment: iterating over an array like with the size of 1000 is pretty fast. creating/destroing a new thread etc itself takes a lot of time.

Comment: As a side note - You have concurrent reads/ writes on unprotected memory - don't do this, as you can't expect your values to be uncorrupted. (search for mutexes)

Comment: Well first of all you have a race condition...

Comment: (off topic) number[i] = 10000000/th;  this is always the same value

Comment: to parallelize you should have each thread run on different memory not the same. So like one thread on index 0 - 2000 and the second on index 2001 - 3999.

Comment: @UKMonkey for workloads like this I'd not propose to use mutexes, but resort to `std::async<>` instead.

Comment: @cdonat doing so would require changing a[], but yes, looks like a tidy way to do this.

Comment: @Carcigenicate  the workload is not very petty, for one thread doing a number[i]* 1000 write memory. And if so, we should not have obtain speedup on other machines.

Comment: @Hay  This is just a test program, I have the need like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The given example is bad for multithreaded execution, because the tasks are not really splittable among threads.

Threads compete for the **single shared resource**: `a[1000]` array. The contention on the shared memory causes high **inter-cache traffic** due to [cache coherence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_coherence) protocol. See [MESI protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MESI_protocol) for the details.

The actual overhead of the contention depends on the particular system, CPU and memory configuration. You may observe significantly different results even on the same machine, depending on which CPUs the program is executed on:

```
// CPUs within the same NUMA node
$ numactl -C 0,1 ./a.out
24.3272

// CPUs from different NUMA nodes
$ numactl -C 0,6 ./a.out
42.1547
```

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're seeing is that the optimiser is eliding the single-threaded loop.

```
long long int number[th];

for(int i=0; i<th; i++){
    number[i] = 10000000/th;
}
```

After this loop, the result of assigning to `number` is never read, so the observable effect of filling `number` with numbers is the same as the observable effect of doing nothing (see "as-if rule").

you can demonstrate this with a small program:

```
int main(){

    int th = 1;
    long long int number[th];

    for(int i=0; i<th; i++){
        number[i] = 10000000/th;
    }
}
```

which with gcc and clang, with optimisations on, compiles to:

```
main:
        xor     eax, eax
        ret
```

I suspect what is happening is that the addition of threads to this trivial example is preventing the optimiser from seeing that the result of the assignments is never used, so the threaded version actually fills a vector whereas the single-thread version does not.

demo: https://godbolt.org/g/lewly3